# iterating list using _api rest - Not working

Tags: rest, json

I can see 2 records in the console but my alert doesnt print out any data and doesnt append to the table either.

See below and thanks in advance

```
 // begin work to call across network
    var requestUri = "http://devmachine/dev/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Contact')/items?$select=FirstName,FullName";
    // execute AJAX request
    $.ajax({
    url: requestUri,
    type: "GET",
    headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
    success: function(data){

    //alert(data.d.FullName);
    var newRows = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
       newRows += "<tr><td>" + data.d[i].FirstName + 
                  "</td><td>" + data.d[i].FullName + "</td></tr>";
    }
    $("table tr:first").after(newRows);
    alert(newRows);


    },
    error: function(){
    alert("Failed to get data");
    }
    });
```

Comment: So you're saying this "alert(data.d.FullName);" IS able to print a result?

Comment: @ChristoffeldeGruyter "my alert doesnt print out any data"

Comment: Sorry, went over it too quickly

Answer (score 1):

The data are under: `data.d.result`

 Try this:

```
var newRows = "";
$(data.d.results).each(function (index) {

       newRows += "<tr><td>" + data.d.results[index].FirstName + 
                  "</td><td>" + data.d.results[index].FullName + "</td></tr>";
    });
```

Comment: Thanks guys just had a looked at the json and Yes missed results.Also when i use url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('ZipCodes')

i get error until i use my full path URL.Basically _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl isnt working.Why is this?

Cheers

Comment: In general u have to use Result when the query can return more items. If u use /item(ID) u don not have to use result. Enjoy!

Comment: and btw use always the browser console/debugger to watch js obj ;)

Comment: @naijacoder You never are able to get the _spPageContextInfo object? Or simply at page load? If it's a problem at page load, be sure to use _spbodyonloadfunctionnames.push("MyFunctionName")